# Promise.all() not always resolved - edited to add the code for both functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, promise

I'm using the following code to update the state but the Promise.all() array isn't always resolved before the final function is called. Sometimes, the entire array is populated but it usually isn't.

I'm logging the Promise.all() array to the console just so I can see what's happening. What is really peculiar is the state is always updated properly but calling the individual elements in the array often returns "undefined". I need to use the individual elements to create a new array for displaying later which is why I'm accessing them.

Please help me either figure out how to access the array when it's finished updating or a better way to process the entire thing.

```
class X {
  componentDidMount() {
    const numTiles = 3;

    for (let i = 0; i < numTiles; i++) {
      Promise.all([
        this.fetchSong(), // returns JSON from SQLite DB
        this.fetchArtists(),  // returns JSON from SQLite DB
      ]) 
        .then(values => {
          this.testing(values);
        });
    }
  }

  testing(arr) {
    console.log("arr: ", arr);
    console.log("arr[0]: ", arr[0]);
    console.log("arr[0].id: ", arr[0].id);
    console.log("arr[0].name: ", arr[0].name);
    console.log("arr[0].artist: ", arr[0].artist);
    console.log("arr[1]: ", arr[1]);
    console.log("arr[1][0]: ", arr[1][0]);
    console.log("arr[1][1]: ", arr[1][1]);
    console.log("arr[1][0].artist: ", arr[1][0].artist);
    console.log("arr[1][1].artist: ", arr[1][1].artist);
  }
}
```

Edit: code for fetchSong() and fetchArtists() added.

```
fetchSong() {
    let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 1;  // get random number for id
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Bingo.getSong(id).then(song => {
        resolve(song);
      });
    });
  }

  fetchArtists() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let arr = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        Bingo.getArtist(id).then(artist => {
          arr.push(artist);
        });
        resolve(arr);
      };
    });
  }
```

The console screenshot below shows the Promise.all() array has been populated but the array elements are still missing.

[image: Console screenshot]

Comment: That simply looks like `.fetchArtists()` returns an empty list.

Comment: The results from fetchSong() are populated in arr[0] and the results from fetchArtists() are in arr[1][0] and arr[1][1]. An example is the bottom one in the console -> arr[1][0].artist: random artist 8.

Comment: But printing `arr[1]` says `[]`...

Comment: Can you add the code for `.fetchSong()` and `.fetchArtists()` too? I have an inkling as to what's going on...

Comment: No problem, I edited the original post for you. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think you should add return inside then function. return resolve(song);

Comment: @DRobinson Yeah, okay, that clears it up. Lemme just answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the implementation of `fetchArtists`, which resolved before any of the single-artist-fetching promises were resolved.

I've also simplified `fetchSong`, but the gist of `fetchArtists` now is you store the promises that will resolve to single artists, then wait for all of them to resolve. There's no reason to add a `.then()` there, since as you know, `Promise.all()` will resolve with an array of resolved values anyhow.

```
fetchSong() {
  const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 1;
  return Bingo.getSong(id);
}

fetchArtists() {
  const fetchPromises = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    fetchPromises.push(Bingo.getArtist(id));
  }
  return Promise.all(fetchPromises);
}
```

Comment: It's so easy when you know how :)

Thank you very much for the assistance. I have a long way to go before I can navigate code writing with such finesse but the road is made that much smoother with assistance from kind people such as yourself.

Thank you again.